# How to show a textbox when a specific listbox item is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a listbox in a gridview where last item is called "other". I need to find a way so that when "other" is selected a textbox is shown for the user to type in a value, and if it is deselected then the textbox will be hidden.

I'm trying to do this on the client-side (with jquery or javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
 Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim str As String
        str = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        If str.Equals("other") Then
            TextBox1.Visible = True
        Else
            TextBox1.Visible = False
        End If

    End Sub
```

But if you can't associate directly the event you would create the association in the load event:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In gvProcesos.Rows     
   Dim ListBox1 As ListBox = row.FindControl("MylistBox")  
   AddHandler  ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged
Next
```

An in the client side you could try these

```
   $('#<%=gdRows.ClientID %>').find('span[id$="lblID"]')
```

but substitute span for the rendered HTML control.

Comment: right, I understand what your saying. that is a server side solution possibly. I was looking for a client side perhaps with jquery.

Comment: That is not a server-side solution. By the way, you might need to use "str = ListBox1.SelectedItem(1).ToString" on the line 3. SelectedItem is an array, where "0" is ValueMember and "1" is DisplayMember, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

after much testing, I got to this as my solution using straight javascript

my server code

```
oListBox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ShowHideTextbox('" & oListBox.ClientID & "','" & oTextbox.ClientID & "','" & oLabel.ClientID & "');")
```

my javascript function

```
    function ShowHideTextbox(oDropID, oTextID, oLabelID) {
    var ddl = document.getElementById(oDropID);
    var oTextbox = document.getElementById(oTextID);
    var oLabel = document.getElementById(oLabelID);
    var bShow = false;
    for (i = 0; i < ddl.length; i++) {
        if (ddl[i].selected) {
            if (ddl[i].text == "Other") bShow = true;
        }
    }
    if (bShow) {
        oLabel.style.display = 'inline';
        oTextbox.style.display = 'inline';
        oTextbox.focus();
    } else {
        oLabel.style.display = 'none'; 
        oTextbox.style.display = 'none'; 
    }
}
```

in my case I have a label and textbox that I am showing / hiding
I am not sure yet if it is firefox compatible.
I also have to work out for myself an initial state of the textbox depending upon values from database.